# Is there a way to retrieve a column specified by the user from a MySQL database?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a MySQL database of some measurements taken by a device and I'm looking for a way to retrieve specific columns from it, where the user chooses what columns he needs from a python interface/front end. All the solutions I've seen till now either retrieves all columns or had the columns specified in the code itself.
Is there a possible way I could do this?
Thanks!

Comment: define user? is it a application user or MySQL database user? And you should also provide the python code and SQL create statements.

Comment: I was thinking I'd create a basic HTML form or something through which someone can pick off certain columns. I wanted to get the column names as input to my python code amd then run a query.

Answer (score 1):

Your query can look something like this :

```
select 
      table_name, table_schema, column_name 
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema in ('schema1', 'schema2') 
and column_name like '%column_name%'
order by table_name;
```

you can definitely pass the `column_name` as a parameter(fetch it from python code) run it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

```
import MySQLdb

#### #GET COLUMN NAME FROM USER PRESENT WITH IN TABLE
column = input()

#### #Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect("host","username","password","DB_name" )

#### #prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

#### #execute SQL query using execute() method.
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM TABLE")

# Fetch a all rows using fetchall() method.
result_set = cursor.fetchall()

for row in result_set:
    print(row[column])

# disconnect from server
db.close()
```

OR you can use .execute() to run a specific query with column name.